# RGBA pixel data into D3DLOCKED_RECT

Tags: c++, pixel, rgba, direct3d9

I'm trying to update a 128x128 D3DLOCKED_RECT with sub images using the following code, but it seems to squish them down along the top, the X offset is ignored and the y offset is 60 percent off.

I've also tried to make the texture the correct size and copy it into a 128x128 texture at the correct location using RECT, however this is very slow and didn't seem to work correctly when I attempted it. There must be way to do it using the raw pixel data?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

EDIT: I got it semi working using the below code, the locations are now correct and the sizes. But it's only using the blue channel and everything is grey scale (blue scale?)

```
srcdata = (byte *) pixels;

dstdata = (unsigned int *)lockrect.pBits;

for (y = yoffset; y < (yoffset + height); y++)
{
    for (x = xoffset; x < (xoffset + width); x++)
    {
        dstdata[ ( y * lockrect.Pitch / dstbytes + x ) + 0] = (unsigned int)srcdata[0];
        dstdata[ ( y * lockrect.Pitch / dstbytes + x ) + 1] = (unsigned int)srcdata[1];
        dstdata[ ( y * lockrect.Pitch / dstbytes + x ) + 2] = (unsigned int)srcdata[0];
        dstdata[ ( y * lockrect.Pitch / dstbytes + x ) + 3] = (unsigned int)srcdata[3];

        srcdata += srcbytes;
    }
}'
```

END Edit

Test call after creating the 128x128 texture:

```
int x, y;
byte    temp[132*132*4];

// Test texture (pink and black checker)
for( y = 0; y < 16; y++ )
{
    for( x = 0; x < 16; x++ )
    {
        if(( y < 8 ) ^ ( x < 8 ))
            ((uint *)&temp)[y*16+x] = 0xFFFF00FF;
        else ((uint *)&temp)[y*16+x] = 0xFF000000;
    }
}

UpdateSubImage (0, 0, 16, 16, temp )
```

The update Fuction:

```
void UpdateSubImage (int xoffset, int yoffset, int width, int height, const 
GLvoid *pixels)
{
int x, y;
int srcbytes = 4; //Hard coded for now, as all tests are RGBA
int dstbytes = 4; // ^
byte *srcdata;
byte *dstdata;

D3DLOCKED_RECT lockrect;

pTexture->LockRect( 0, &lockrect, NULL, 0);

srcdata = (byte *) pixels;
dstdata = (byte *) lockrect.pBits;
dstdata += (yoffset * width + xoffset) * dstbytes;

for (y = yoffset; y < (yoffset + height); y++)
{
    for (x = xoffset; x < (xoffset + width); x++)
    {
        if (srcbytes == 1)
        {
            if (dstbytes == 1)
                dstdata[0] = srcdata[0];
            else if (dstbytes == 4)
            {
                dstdata[0] = srcdata[0];
                dstdata[1] = srcdata[0];
                dstdata[2] = srcdata[0];
                dstdata[3] = srcdata[0];
            }
        }
        else if (srcbytes == 3)
        {
            if (dstbytes == 1)
                dstdata[0] = ((int) srcdata[0] + (int) srcdata[1] + (int) srcdata[2]) / 3;
            else if (dstbytes == 4)
            {
                dstdata[0] = srcdata[2];
                dstdata[1] = srcdata[1];
                dstdata[2] = srcdata[0];
                dstdata[3] = 255;
            }
        }
        else if (srcbytes == 4)
        {
            if (dstbytes == 1)
                dstdata[0] = ((int) srcdata[0] + (int) srcdata[1] + (int) srcdata[2]) / 3;
            else if (dstbytes == 4)
            {
                dstdata[0] = srcdata[2];
                dstdata[1] = srcdata[1];
                dstdata[2] = srcdata[0];
                dstdata[3] = srcdata[3];
            }
        }

        // advance
        srcdata += srcbytes;
        dstdata += dstbytes;
    }
}

pTexture->UnlockRect(0);
}
```

What the output looks like:

[image]

What the output should look like:
[image]

Comment: in your edit, check the third `srcdata[0]` line, should be `[2]`.  Also, if `dstdata` is `int*`, then `stdata[ ( y * lockrect.Pitch / dstbytes + x ) + 1]` will probably be the next pixel.  Which means the assignment is only setting the lower part of the int, which is the `BLUE` channel for `ARGB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help :), in the end the following code worked:

Can it be made faster?

```
for (y = yoffset; y < (yoffset + height); y++)
{
    for (x = xoffset; x < (xoffset + width); x++)
    {
        ARGB pixel;
        pixel.r = srcdata[0];
        pixel.g = srcdata[1];
        pixel.b = srcdata[2];
        pixel.a = srcdata[3];
        memcpy( &dstdata[lockrect.Pitch * y + dstbytes * x], &pixel, dstbytes );

        srcdata += srcbytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but you'll better ask a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that the data accessable through `lockrect.pBits` is linear in memory. This is in general not the case. Instead you have a constant offset between your rows which is defined by the `lockrect.Pitch` value.

To get the address of a pixel in the destination use:

```
byte * destAddr = (lockrect.pBits + y * lockrect.Pitch + 4 * x); 
// for 32 bit images. For other formats adjust the hard-coded 4.
```